# Wordpress inserting styles

Tags: css, wordpress

Has anyone had any experience and possibly know what is causing wordpress to add extra css to our pages.

Examples of the css being inserted below:

```
<style>div.wp-container-1>div>p:nth-of-type(2){display: none}</style>
<style>div.wp-container-16{display: none}</style>
<style>div.accordion>div:nth-of-type(7){display: none}</style>
```

I've gone and uninstalled all the plugins, tried incognito mode, cleared my cache and it hasn't helped.

Comment: That looks like a template insertion.  have you checked all of your themes?

Comment: If you are using gutenberg it might be that you are adding rules to some of the blocks in the editor via the GUI. Those could then be printed to the page like the above ones are.

Comment: I have check al our themes and have checked the blocks that there aren't any rules being added. It is happening randomly on different pages throughout the site